# Intellij jar artifact with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf gets,Template mode "HTML" has not been configured

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, thymeleaf

With the mode specified in application.properties

```
#spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
```

Intellij Run Debug works fine, but executing the jar from the command line gets the following when the browser attempts to open a page:

2018-12-24 12:16:13.957 ERROR   --- [0.1-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-12
7.0.0.1-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "result-sm": Template mode "HTML" has not been configured
Dec 24, 2018 12:16:14 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing fa
iled; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Template mode "HTML" has not been configured]
 with root cause
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Template mode "HTML" has not been configured
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:256)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
        at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
        at org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)

If the mode declaration is deleted from application.properties the jar assumes that the mode is LEGACYHTML5 and it tries to do nekoHTML parsing which isnt HTML5 at all.  For example it says that a `<linK>` doesnt have a matching `</link>`.

It seems that this should have a simple workaround, but I havent been able to find it.

Thanks

EDIT: Added code for template resolver.  I copied this copied this code from another site without a great deal of understanding.  It was modified to fit the actual project structure.  I ran it with the debugger and it did not seem to have been called.

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
public class ThymeleafConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver() {

        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();

        templateResolver.setPrefix("templates/");
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {

        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }
```

Comment: Do you have anything configured for your template resolver?  If so, please post the code (it should be in a class with the `@Configuration` annotation).

Comment: Added template resolver code.

Comment: You should use the static `TemplateMode.HTML` instead of "HTML" when you call `templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");`.  Then comment out `spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML` and give that a go.  I don't know for sure whether that this will solve the issue.  If it doesn't, can you also post your `result-sm` template?

Comment: Also note that you are effectively switching off the default configuration for Spring Boot by including the configuration.  If you want to go that route, you will likely want to annotate with `@EnableWebMvc` as well.  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-default-mvc-configuration

Comment: I made the suggested changes, but I am still getting "TemplateMode HTML not configured."  I set break points in the ThymeleafConfig above and none were triggered which leads me to believe it was not called.  It was placed at the same level in the source tree as the Application main.  I didnt post results-sm because it is 600 lines of very convoluted html and js and works in Intellij.  I will post it if you think it necessary.

Comment: Can you instead try hitting a very basic page without the closing link tag?  Like `<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="some.css"></head><body>Russell</body></html>`?   Doing so can tell you whether or not it's something in your HTML.

Comment: You shouldn't have this issue in a fresh Spring Boot project, so there's something off...

Comment: To isolate, another thing you can also try is removing the config and the `spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML` line entirely and have Spring Boot manage it all.

Comment: I created the basic page as suggested.  Same set of problems, works on Intellij, not as a jar.  Without the mode setting in application.properties, it defaults to HTML5.  Intellij detects the error and changes the mode to HTML.  The jar tries the HTML% mode and fails on the link.  Same issues if I remove ThymeleafConfig.

Comment: I set breakpoints in ThymeleafConfig, but none are triggered.  Is it ever being executed?  Am I missing something else.  This is not a fresh project, but it is the first time that I tried to create a jar.

Comment: At least we know it's not the HTML.  In your pom.xml, do you have `spring-boot-maven-plugin` listed?  It's needed to create an executable jar according to the docs.  You can see whether you're missing any steps here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html

Comment: It appears that the beans are never being called.  I changed the bean signatures to match those in the Tymeleaf 3 Migration guide, but still they were not called.